# How to load uiview by selecting row from uitableview 

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

My app is a view based app and i added following components on it

Five uibuttons

On selecting any button drop down in the form of uitableview

So it has Five tableviews as well.

My problem is how to load detail view by selecting any row ,i didn't added navcontrllr and this is code for .....but this not working nthing happens on selecting row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    if([holidayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"Sunday")
    {
        UIViewController *control = [[SundayController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MyViewController" bundle: nil];
        UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: control];
        [self presentModalViewController: navControl animated: YES];
        [control release];
    }
    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
if ([holidayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"Sunday")
```

compares the pointers and not the actual strings. Have you tried using

```
if ([[holidayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Sunday"])
```

?